# QGIS Adding the CSV points including Lat & on to the British National Grid Project CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ordnance-survey

I have a problem with adding the CSV data to my QGS project with CRS set on the British National Grid EPSG:27700.

[image]

In turn, my points are at the beginning of the coordinate system like you see below:

[image]

I tried to change the CRS for this CSV input to EPSG 3857 Pseudo-Mercator or WGS84. It didn't work at all.

According the thread below:

[Adding points defined by Latitude and Longitude to map using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141024/adding-points-defined-by-latitude-and-longitude-to-map-using-qgis)

it looks like the QGIS doesn't recognize these point coordinates under this system.

[Adding points defined by Latitude and Longitude to map using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141024/adding-points-defined-by-latitude-and-longitude-to-map-using-qgis)

Moreover, it's not able to transform the On the fly to the EPSG:27700.

How can I add them properly? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coordinates are clearly Lat/Lon, so you need to choose `WGS 84 | EPSG:4326` as `Geometry CRS` while importing the file.

[image]

They will be projected on the fly to your project CRS for display purposes. If you want to work with them in EPSG:27700, you need to reproject the layer **after** you have added it in EPSG:4326. You can do this by `saving the layer as...` or running `reproject` from processing toolbox.

Comment: I've run reproject layer. In the target CRS should I select the EPSG:27700 British National Grid?

Comment: yes _(need to add 12 more characters)_

Comment: What 12 more characters?

Comment: Thannk you for that. I will try later. Although my experience learned me, that in situations as I am experiencing now the best way is set up a completely new QGIS project instead of fighting with the current problem. I will upvote your solution, as other people did. That's the best example, that something was definitely wrong with my project.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. I will do the try on another occasion definitely. Thank you very much for your help